# Rename and move the file to folder using shutil.move

Tags: python, shutil, python-watchdog

```
def safe_copy(self,src,out_dir):
    if not os.path.exists(out_dir):
        os.makedirs(out_dir)
    name = os.path.basename(src) 
    shutil.move(src,os.path.join(out_dir,'{}'.format(append_timestamp(name))))


safe_copy("\\\\server\\drive\\folder\\filename","\\\\server\\drive\\folder2")
```

I have the above function to move the file from source folder to destination folder. This function is working but the file is moving without the file extension and the file became unsupported.

Can anyone please advise me on this issue.

Comment: You can use the copy2() function from the shutil module instead of the move() function. The copy2() function will retain the file extensions when copying files from the source folder to the destination folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def safe_copy(src,out_dir):
   if not os.path.exists(out_dir):
     os.makedirs(out_dir)
   name = os.path.basename(src)
   shutil.move(src,os.path.join(out_dir,'{}'.format(append_timestamp(name))  + "." + src.split(".")[-1]))
```

If you are using this move method. You need to add the extension in src file.